# How to apply :hover to an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover

I want to apply the hover state remotely, by hovering on a different object. But I want to name the object that has its hover activated rather than have it be by DOM relationship to the item being hovered over.

```
<style>
img:hover {border: thin red solid;}
</style>

<li id="hover-over-me">Dogs</li>
<img src="dog.jpg" />
```

I haven't found a javascript or jquery method that allows you to apply the hover pseudo-class effect to an element remotely (ie independently of it actually being hovered). Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean specifically the CSS `:hover` pseudo selector, then one element can only trigger it on another insofar as a relationship can be established in CSS:

http://jsfiddle.net/tFSWt/

*example as siblings:*

```
<span>Sibling </span><img src = "http://dummyimage.com/120x90/f00/fff.png&text=my+image" />

img:hover { border: 2px dashed blue; }
span:hover + img { border: 2px dashed blue; }
```

*example as ancestor/descendant:*

```
<span>Parent 
    <img src = "http://dummyimage.com/120x90/f00/fff.png&text=my+image" />
</span>

img:hover { border: 2px dashed blue; }
span:hover img { border: 2px dashed blue; }
```

Otherwise you'll need to rely on JavaScript to select the related element and set the style on either by inline styling, or by adding a class that provides the appropriate style.

Comment: so I guess the short answer to my q is 'you can't' ? :p

Comment: @Damon: If you mean triggering the `:hover` CSS pseudo selector from JavaScript, then unfortunately that's right, you can't. But you *can* define handlers for mouse events in JavaScript and trigger those.

Comment: yeah.. that is what I meant. I know about adding/removing classes, but hoped I could do it in a more straightforward way.

Comment: Is it perhaps possible to "force" the pseudo selector in a similar manner to the "Toggle Element State" feature in Chrome's Web Inspector (version 14 and above)? Here's the relevant changeset: http://trac.webkit.org/changeset/90397/trunk/Source/WebCore/inspector/front-end/StylesSidebarPane.js. Or is that just adding classes and then hiding them in the inspector?

Comment: @peterjmag: I've not heard of any way to force it in the current standards. That webkit changeset seems like it's internal, but not sure.

Answer (score 3):

http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/3304b

```
<style> 
img:hover,img.hovered {border: 5px red solid;} 
</style> 
<ul>
   <li id="hover-over-me">Dogs</li>
</ul> 
<img src="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/_7VyEDKFMA2U/TOX9ZL7KRPI/AAAAAAAAACM/-XSoYjePBPk/s1600/cute-puppy-dog-wallpapers.jpg" /> 
<script> 
$("li").mouseenter(function(){ 
   $("img").addClass('hovered'); 
}); 

$("li").mouseout(function(){ 
   $("img").removeClass('hovered'); 
}); 


</script>
```

Comment: That does *not* trigger a CSS hover.

Comment: Why are people even voting this up?

Comment: I know about adding classes to items and hover functions, I wanted the pseudo-class :hover to be applied, though I don't believe it's actually possible, which is too bad.